# How to summarize/resume json object in another json object

Tags: ruby

How can I summarize a json data inside another json data, that is, put all the `key:value` ​​inside another json without having to define again.

Ex:

```
default_headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

special_headers = { default_headers, 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxx'}

# special_headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
#    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxx' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) the new hash into the one you already have:

```
{
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}.merge('Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxx')
# {:"User-Agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36", :"Content-Type"=>"application/json", :Authorization=>"Bearer xxxxxxx"}
```